# MethodDecorator.Fody in Xamarin.Forms PCL not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, fody

I am trying out Fody for a Xamarin Forms app. However, I keep getting the following issue

[image: Error]

Now I tried the same code in a .NET console app and everything works like a charm.

Looking into the source code for MethodDecorator.Fody, it seems to be an issue with the following line in ***Reference.cs***

```
public ReferenceFinder(ModuleDefinition moduleDefinition) {
            this.moduleDefinition = moduleDefinition;
            var mscorlibAssemblyReference = moduleDefinition.AssemblyReferences.First(a => a.Name == "mscorlib"); //Issue here
            this.mscorlib = moduleDefinition.AssemblyResolver.Resolve(mscorlibAssemblyReference).MainModule;
        }
```

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong? I have attached the sample project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38804059/App1.zip)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have no reference to mscorlib or naming is different in Xamarin. You need to find an assembly which contains basic types like Exception. Once you know how this library named you need to store reference to it in this.mscorlib of ReferenceFinder.